# Call JSON from another activity

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I have one problem. I have an app where you can vote for someone you like. You can vote just one time per day. I save that day when user votes with SharedPreferences, so user can't vote one more time that day. Everything is working okay. I create another activity and from that activity I know user's choice. That means, I know for who user want to vote. My question is: how can I get user's sharedpreferences(day when user vote last time), write it to SharedPreferences (that Vote Activity would know that i choose someone) and do i have to copy the same code from vote Activity to second Activity or I can use my Vote Activity from some place of code? My code with saving Preferences and calling JSON:

```
private void savePreferences(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(file_url);
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String pos = pos1.toString();

            Log.i("12", pos);
            int success;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pos", pos));
                Log.d("request!", pos);

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(VOTE_URL, "POST",
                        params);


                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Successful!", json.toString());

                    Intent i = new Intent(Vote.this, MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Failure!", json.toString());

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Balsuok.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Voting...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to save the json result in sharedpreferences

Comment: I don't need to save json result. I just need to save day when user last time voted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set shared preference like this.

Activity 1 :-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Get shared preference in second activity like this.

Activity2 :-

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
return preferences.getString(key, null);
```

Comment: Just a tip , set the key with your date dd-MM-yyyy... then you will now when the user already voted, if key !=null the user already voted that date

Comment: I just posted the way to how to set and get Shared Pref. It's his wish what he want to put in value.

Comment: And another thing, the best way to get this as you expect is to verify if the user already voted in your webservice, if you validate using SharedPreferences you will lose all your data if the user just clean the app data or delete your app

Comment: Answer to comment 1: I think it's easier to deal with int rather than String. If user have voted yesterday key = 27-11-2013 and today he couldn't vote because key!=null. So, i think it isn't a good way to solve this
Answer to comment 2: I thought that I can't do better that SharedPreferences. I would be very grateful to find out the way to identify the user :)

Comment: What is a better way to identify user that he voted already that day?

Comment: The best way for me, is to send the device ID to the webservice then you register that information on your database and just give back a true/false (sucess/failure), so the device can store this on sharedPreferences, just to set the button as available to the user, if you can't get this information in your sharedPreferences because the app lose the data you just let the user click the fav button, if the action will be completed is up to the webservice... I think this is better, but that is what I think, I can be wrong :)